# Visual Studio Code, how to make local file link open default program

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code text editor highlights and allows to follow links, this includes local file URLs:

[image]

Ctrl+click opens the file in a new editor tab:

[image]

Is it possible to configure VS Code is some way to open the file in default program instead upon ctrl+click / follow link? (e.g. html file in web browser, mp3 in media player etc.)

Any setting, extension or different text markdown will do.

Comment: OS is Windows 10

Comment: I am still looking for a generic feature for doing this as I often have filenames in comments or strings. I need something that would work in any language.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a default way in vscode to set open a file with default program.
However, there are extensions to deal with it. For example: [Open in Application](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-open-in-application&ssr=false#overview)

Comment: "Open in Application" still not quite what needed, Follow link / ctrl+click still opens file in the VS editor tab